# Title is not coming while sharing post on Google Plus

Tags: wordpress, post, google-plus, custom-code

I am trying to share following post/page on my google plus account https://www.schoolmykids.com/parenting/importance-of-father-daughter-relationship/
Instead of TITLE of the blog, google plus is showing me just the site name.

Please suggest how to resolve this issue except for my actual blog/article page all pages are showing correct tile while sharing on google plus.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your page to add meta tags with Open Graph properties.  This should work for sharing either on Google+ or Facebook.  Using these OpenGraph properties you can specify descriptive meta data about your page such as your page title, a brief description, an image, etc.

**For example:**

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Importance of the Father-Daughter Relationship" />
```

**Here are a couple of links to get you started:**

https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters